# Importing existing project in Titanium Studio

Tags: titanium

I have install titanium studio 3.2.3.201404290739 in my windows 7 and installed other sdk as suggested by studio. Now I want to import an existing project in studio but when I select File -> Import... -> General -> Existing Folder as New Project, it gives java.lang.NullPointException if I double click on Existing Folder as New Project and if I click on Next button it opens a window "Promote to Project" but this window contains nothing.

Please suggest me how can I import my project in titanium studio.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the folder you are importing is actually a Titanium Project, Try Importing it as :

Import-> Titanium -> Existing Mobile Project.

Just Browse to your directory, and Press Open.It will work.

Comment: Hi Dragon, thanks for the reply but my project is not titanium project, its Dreamweaver project. Its mentioned on titanium site as well https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Importing+an+Existing+Project